# Use interfaces without importing them

Tags: typescript

I'm currently working on a new project that has a `client` and a `server` folder, where the names speak for them.

The client is a React app whereas the server are Google Cloud functions powered by Express.

I have a lot of types that are shared (e.g. the `User` interface), but currently, I have a `types` folder with `user.ts` in both of my application folders. Of course, this repetition is far from ideal.

To give you a general idea, this is what the `user.ts` file looks like

```
export default interface IUser {
  id: string;
  email: string;
  uid: string;
  username: string;
  balance: number;
}
```

Is there any way I can share these types throughout my application? Maybe even without importing them? I've read about using a `d.ts` file, but that seems like a dirty hack?

Comment: Why not *one* interface source shared via appropriate method? This could trivially start as an automated file copy (although it might be a better long-term approach to move to packages or shared sub-repo etc). Point is, there is *one* definition in code that is the source.

Comment: @user2864740 Yeah converting to a real monorepo has crossed my mind. But I would still have to import the interfaces when needed, no?

Comment: The same interface definitions (or a structurally-equivalent, as used, stand-in) need to be present for TS to compile, yes. This is a trade-off of static typing.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename `user.ts` file to `user.d.ts` and then declare your interfaces in order to avoid importing and declare and use in whole application codes.

```
declare interface IUser {
  id: string;
  email: string;
  uid: string;
  username: string;
  balance: number;
}
```

More information documented here: [typescriptlang handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html)

Comment: > I've read about using a d.ts file, but that seems like a dirty hack?

Isn't a `.d.ts` file meant for an external library that is not typed? And not for your own components?

Comment: No that's not a hack and that's the typescript backbone feature. but I suggest you to prevent writing all your interfaces into ```.d.ts``` files(Just a hint for clean code best practices)

Comment: So you're effectively advising against your own answer?